# Writting data from pubsub to bigtable via cloud functions

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-bigtable

I am a beginner at cloud big table and have big issues using cloud functions writing data from pub/sub to bigtable.

Cloud functions gets the messages from pubsub, but the issue is in the next step, writing it into bigtable.

The message is created in a python  script and sent to pub/sub.

One example for a message:

> b'{"eda":2.015176,"temperature":33.39,"bvp":-0.49,"x_acc":-36.0,"y_acc":-38.0,"z_acc":-128.0,"heart_rate":83.78,"iddevice":15.0,"timestamp":"2019-12-01T20:01:36.927Z"}'

For writing it into bigtable I created a table:

```
 from google.cloud import bigtable 
 from google.cloud.bigtable import column_family

 client = bigtable.Client(project="projectid", admin=True) 
 instance = client.instance("bigtableinstance")
 table = instance.table("bigtable1")
 print('Creating the {} table.'.format(table)) 
 print('Creating columnfamily cf1 with Max Version GC rule...')
 max_versions_rule = column_family.MaxVersionsGCRule(2)
 column_family_id = 'cf1'
 column_families = {column_family_id: max_versions_rule}
 if not table.exists():
     table.create(column_families=column_families)
     print("Table {} is created.".format(table)) 
 else:
     print("Table {} already exists.".format(table))
```

This works without problems.

Now I tried to write the message via pub/sub to bigtable with the following python code in cloud functions using the main method:

```
import json
import base64
import os
from google.cloud import bigtable
from google.cloud.bigtable import column_family, row_filters


project_id = os.environ.get('projetid', 'UNKNOWN')
INSTANCE = 'bigtableinstance'
TABLE = 'bigtable1'

client = bigtable.Client(project=project_id, admin=True)
instance = client.instance(INSTANCE)

colFamily = "cf1"
def writeToBigTable(table, data):
#    Parameters row_key (bytes) – The key for the row being created.
#    Returns A row owned by this table.
        row_key = data[colFamily]['iddevice'].value.encode()
        row = table.row(row_key)
        for colFamily in data.keys():
            for key in data[colFamily].keys():
                row.set_cell(colFamily,
                                        key,
                                        data[colFamily][key])
        table.mutate_rows([row])
        return data

def selectTable():
    stage = os.environ.get('stage', 'dev')
    table_id = TABLE + stage
    table = instance.table(table_id)
    return table


def main(event, context):
    data = base64.b64decode(event['data']).decode('utf-8')
    print("DATA: {}".format(data))
    eda, temperature, bvp, x_acc, y_acc, z_acc, heart_rate, iddevice, timestamp = data.split(',')

    table = selectTable()

    data = {'eda': eda,
         'temperature': temperature,
         'bvp': bvp,
         'x_acc':x_acc,
         'y_acc':y_acc,
         'z_acc':z_acc,
         'heart_rate':heart_rate,
         'iddevice':iddevice,
         'timestamp':timestamp}
    writeToBigTable(table, data)
    print("Data Written: {}".format(data))
```

I tried different versions but cannot find a solution.

Thanks for the help.

All the best

Dominik

Comment: Because you are a beginner in BigTable, I have to ask you this question: Do you have high throughput concern?

Comment: No there is no high throughput. It is a prototype with a small data set.

Comment: Ok, take care of cost of BigTable ;-). Up to 1M of write per second, you can use BigQuery stream write for this.

Comment: Can you make sure you are using the most up-to-date version of the client library and then use table. direct_row(row_key) instead of table.row(row_key)

Answer (score 3):

I think this line is wrong:

```
    row_key = data[colFamily]['iddevice'].value.encode()
```

You're passing in the data object, but it doesn't have a 'cf1' property. You also don't have to encode it. Give this a try:

```
    row_key = data['iddevice']
```

Your for loop will also have the same issue. I think this is what you want instead

```
    for col in data.keys():
        row.set_cell(colFamily, key, data[key])
```

Also, I know you're just playing with it, but using a device id as the only value for a rowkey will end up poorly. What is recommended might be to combine the rowkey and the date or one of your other properties (depending on your query,) and use that as your rowkey. There is a document on [Cloud Bigtable schema](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/schema-design) that is helpful, and a [codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-bigtable-intro-java/index.html#0) using a more realistic sample dataset and walks through how to pick a schema for that example. It's in Java, but you can still import the data and run your own queries.

Answer (score 0):

first thanks a lot for the help.

I tried to fix it with you code recommendation which is , but unfortunately it doesn't work now due to other errors.

> AttributeError: 'DirectRow' object has no attribute 'append'

I guess this is within the following line of code

```
        row.set_cell(colFamily,
                     key,
                     data[key])
```

I could imagine that the errors origin is in the split of the string "data"

```
eda, temperature, bvp, x_acc, y_acc, z_acc, heart_rate, iddevice, timestamp = data.split(',')
```

E.g. eda would look like this:

```
"'eda':2.015176"
```

which looks pretty wrong to me.

Especially when I insert it into the following dict:

```
 data = {'eda': eda,....}
```

The error

> AttributeError: 'DirectRow' object has no attribute 'append'
>   seems to say, that there is a problem with the data I want to process with set_cell. There is said set_cell with row as a list or any other iterable of Direct Row Instance. Shouldn't fit a dic for it?

I tried a workaround with a list, but this seems to make it even worse.

```
client = bigtable.Client(project=project_id, admin=True)
instance = client.instance(INSTANCE)

colFamily = "cf1"
def writeToBigTable(table, dat):

    row_key = "{}-{}".format(dat[16], dat[17])
    row = table.row(row_key)
    for n in range(len(dat)):
        row.set_cell(colFamily,
                     dat[n],
                     dat[n+9])
    table.mutate_rows([row])
    return dat

def selectTable():
    stage = os.environ.get('stage', 'dev')
    table_id = TABLE + stage
    table = instance.table(table_id)
    return table


def main(event, context):
    data = base64.b64decode(event['data']).decode('utf-8')
    print("DATA: {}".format(data))
    var_1, eda, var_2, temperature, var_3, bvp, var_4, x_acc, var_5, y_acc, var_6, z_acc, var_7, heart_rate, var_8, iddevice, var_9, timestamp = data.replace(':',',').split(',')

    table = selectTable(); dat = [var_1, var_2, var_3, var_4, var_5, var_6, var_7, var_8, var_9, eda, temperature, bvp, x_acc, y_acc, z_acc, heart_rate, iddevice, timestamp]; 

#   data = {'eda': eda,
#         'temperature': temperature,
#         'bvp': bvp,
#         'x_acc':x_acc,
#         'y_acc':y_acc,
#         'z_acc':z_acc,
#         'heart_rate':heart_rate,
#         'iddevice':iddevice,
#         'timestamp':timestamp}
    writeToBigTable(table, dat)
    print("Data Written: {}".format(data))
```

I am really hard stuck at this problem and have no further ideas how to solve it.

Comment: The way you had it before was fine, you don't need to do it as a list. Not sure why you're getting that append error and can look into it a bit more. Also, on this site, I'd recommend replying to answers and editing your question rather than creating a new answer with your updated code. That makes it easier for others to follow along and help.